# Migrate JIRA project from one instance to other

Tags: jira

We have a JIRA instance installed on our side and our client is using that. Now client have purchased license of JIRA on Demand and want us to migrate their project from our JIRA to their.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance
Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

Check out Altasian [Splitting+a JIRA instance](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Splitting+a+JIRA+instance) page:

> Occasionally an organisation may need to split its existing JIRA instance into two separate instances. For example, there might be a requirement to have some particular projects in one JIRA instance, and other projects in a second instance.

Basicly, It's done by [backing up the project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Backing+Up+Data) and [restoring it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Restoring+Data) on the new server.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a nice tutorial here:
http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingforme/2012/12/jira-migrating-certain-projects-from-instance/

As described [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/24187/is-there-a-tool-or-method-to-export-a-project-from-one-instance-of-jira-test-and-import-the-project-into-another-jira-instance-production), there is a Plugin in the Atlassian Marketplace, that lets you copy the  configuration: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.awnaba.projectconfigurator.projectconfigurator